# Partial image comparison using RMagick!

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I need to compare parts/sections of two images using RMagick (Ruby binding for ImageMagick). Has anyone had anything to do with it.

I am using `compare_channel` method to generate the image! I have read up the RMagick docs and the RMagick examples from the docs and I get the feeling that I could use
`mask` somehow, but not sure how?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the results of [Image#export_pixels_to_string](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#export_pixels_to_str) should do the trick:

```
area1_str = image1.export_pixels_to_string(xpos, ypos, width, height)
area2_str = image2.export_pixels_to_string(xpos, ypos, width, height)
if area1_str == area2_str
  puts "Equal"
else
  puts "Different"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm grabbing `RGB` individual values and comparing each `pixel`, using the absolute value and qualifying using a comparator value (i.e. 10).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [find_similar_region](https://rmagick.github.io/image2.html#find_similar_region) will help? Or you could make a copy of each image, crop out the sections of interest, and compare the cropped copies?